# asl logger change filter setting during program runtime (or any other configuration)

Tags: c++, c, macos, logging

I'd like to change ASL logger filter setting from an external utility.

However, I wish to do it with little performence degradation as possible.

currently I do so by creating a special file to hold the logger level parameter, 
and change it by the following command

```
echo LOGGER_LEVEL > /etc/syslog_MODULE.conf
```

in the application that uses the logger, there's a special thread that mmap the file into virtual memory space, and check every interval if new logger level should be committed.

this is the mapping section :

```
const char * mmap_config()
{
    int fd;
    char *data;
    struct stat sbuf;

    if ((fd = open("/tmp/conf", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (stat("/tmp/conf", &sbuf) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        exit(1);
    }

    data = (char *)mmap((caddr_t)0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (data == (caddr_t)(-1)) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }

    return data;
}
```

and this is the loop that look for changes in logger level :

```
int main() {
    const char* x = mmap_config();
    while (1) {
        int y = atoi(x);
        asl_set_filter(log_asl_client, ASL_FILTER_MASK_UPTO(y));
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

perhaps there's a simpler way to do so with smaller performance foot-print ?

thanks

Comment: the optimal solution for me would be to just change the mapped file to commit the filtering level. however, i'd also be grateful to hear about a way that doesn't involve creating new thread for monitoring this parameter.